# how to avoid damaging controller during UART communication

Tags: embedded, uart

i am trying to communicate with my board which uses efm32lg230f256 controller.
I want to buy a cable for RS232 UART communication which properties shown in the table and link bellow.
In the table bellow from the data sheet i cant see to what voltage the controller can accept?
There could be situation where my PC will send a command with a higher values then the controller can handle and damage it.
How can i make sure it wont happen?
Thanks.
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm32lg-datasheet.pdf

https://www.mouser.co.il/datasheet/2/163/DS_C232HD_UART_CABLE-4313.pdf
[image]

[image]

Comment: RS232 is not involved in your situation at all.  RS232 levels *would* damage your board, but your USB-UART cable is (hopefully) a bare one, without the line driver that would boost signals to RS232 levels.  While not *reliable*, *typically* "experimentor" cables ending in bare wires, individual pins, or header are logic levels, while "consumer" cables ending in a D-shaped connector are RS232 levels intended for use when talking to finished equipment in a chassis.  Both may use the same USB-UART chips, it's the extra RS232 line driver that is at issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapter 4.2 of the data sheet shows the maximum values. Since the shown cable works at 3.3V levels, it should match perecftly if you power your controller with 3.3V.